# In Cassandra how to select rows by multiple filters?

Tags: cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli

I have a table like below:
CREATE TABLE test ( a int; b int; c int; d int; PRIMARY KEY () );

I want to select the data with 0 < a < 10 and 0 < b < 10, **how should I set the PRIMARY KEY and how should I run the CQL query?**

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Using range operators (< >) on the partitioning key is not allowed unless you use the ByteOrderedPartitioner which has several drawbacks related to performance.

Else, with the default Murmur3Partitioner, you have two options. First solution:

```
create table test (
    a int,
    b int,
    c int,
    d int,
    primary key ((a,b))
);
```

Then for X in 1..10

```
select * from test where a = X and b in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

Second solution:

```
create table test (
    a int,
    b int,
    c int,
    d int,
    primary key (a,b)
);
```

Then

```
select * from test where a in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) and b >=1 and b <= 10 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however, what if I want is to select the data with 0 < a < 10000 and 0 < b < 10000 ?